# How to add class to ul in pimcore wysiwyg?

Tags: ckeditor, html-lists, wysiwyg, pimcore

I have searched and searched for a solution to this, but I can't seem to find one.

I simply want CKeditor to apply the following HTML style when the unordered list icon (Image) is clicked:

```
< ul class="xyz >
```

Comment: Couldn't you just wrap the whole wysiwyg field like this:
<div class="wysiwyg-content">
   <?=$this->wysiwyg("yourWysiwyg")?>
</div>

And then just use in CSS:
.wysiwyg-content UL {
    // Your CSS here
}

Comment: Then I don't see the change in admin (object wysiwyg), and in frontend  text is not in vertical with first line (second line of text is under the square, if list style is square).

Comment: Then this might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39390662/wysiwyg-in-pimcore-object

Comment: I used that for other tags, like p or span but that don't work with ul. I can't get the < ul class="xyz" > < li .> text </ li>

Comment: Thanks Igor!!! I used your first idea with small changes :) Now I got what I wanted.

Comment: Great Makso :) What were the small changes?

Comment: I add .pimcore_object_panel_edit .pimcore_tag_wysiwyg ul {}, etc. , to pimcore extension css file to se the change in admin part :)

Comment: Great! Thanks for reporting back :)